# SED command to delete empty lines till the first occurrence of sentence

Tags: regex, macos, bash, sed

My input file will be

```
[emptyline]
[emptyline]
aaa
bbb
[emptyline]
cc
dd
```

Here [emptyline] indicates blanklines.

And I need an SED command to change this into

```
aaa
bbb
[emptyline]
cc
dd
```

That is, I need to delete all the blank lines at the top alone.

I need only SED command since i need to use that in bash script.

Additional info its MAC OSx

Comment: Additional info required: what did you try so far?

Comment: I couldn't find a solution for this scenario..I was deleting all the first line in my files using sed that time an empty line after my first line creates this problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the lines are really empty (no whitespace), I would suggest

`sed -n '/./,$p'`, otherwise `sed -n $'/[^ \t]/,$p'`. (The `$'..'` syntax makes bash expand the `\t`, so you don't need a sed that understands it.)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with branching in sed:

```
sed '/^ *$/d; :a; n; ba' file
```

A more efficient solution would be to use a range expression, see [*user2719058's* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19774639/1331399) for how to do this.

It is even more efficient if you can reduce the need for sed, see [*gniourf_gniourf's* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19775127/1331399) for alternatives.

This can be expressed in awk elegantly like this:

```
awk 'NF {f=1} f' file
```

Output in both cases:

```
aaa
bbb

cc
dd
```

#### Explanation

Both alternatives work by looking for the first non-empty line.

With `sed` the pattern `/^ *$/d` will delete all empty lines in the beginning of the file. What follows is a loop that prints the rest of the file.

`awk` will update `NF` for every line, when the line is empty `NF` is zero. This is exploited for setting the print-flag (`f`).

Comment: I am getting the like this.

sed: 1: "/^$/!{:a;p;n;ba;}": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)

Comment: @damienfrancois: added some explanation for the awk answer

Comment: +1 for awk command, sed command in other answer doesn't work.

Comment: @unxnut's command does not work for me. Could you give yours again ?

Comment: @damienfrancois: I was too hasty and didn't test unxnut's answer  well enough. I have rolled-back my answer.

Comment: Using sed branches for this task is ugly overkill and not necessary.

Comment: @user2719058: I agree. I could not find a working range-expression  when I was writing the answer, so I went with the one I knew. I see you have posted a range-expression, +1 I'll put in a reference to it here.

Answer (score 2):

One funny possibility:

```
{ sed -n '/./{p;q}' && cat; } < file
```

And it's really efficient too! (try to benchmark it against the other methods). If you might have some spaces in your first lines, you could do:

```
{ sed -n '/[^[:space:]]/{p;q}' && cat; } < file
```

`sed` does nothing until it reads a character; at this point it prints out the line and exits. Then `cat` outputs the whole thing; so since there's no more `sed` filtering, the data flows much faster through `cat`!

The same with `grep`:

```
{ grep -v -m 1 '^$' && cat; } < file
```

or discarding leading lines with possible spaces:

```
{ grep -v -m 1 '^[[:space:]]*$' && cat; } < file
```

Comment: Creative, I like it :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple one is: `sed '1,/^$/d' file`

It will delete starting at line 1 up to the last blank line prior to the actual content of file; preserving the other blank lines as desired by OP.

Comment: This leaves 1 blank line at start if there are 3 blank lines and more if there are more blank lines. In short this command will work ONLY if there are exactly 2 blank lines.

Comment: @anubhava: it works here the lines of your input probably contain some white space. You can control for that by using this pattern instead: `'1,/^ *$/d'`.

Comment: @Thor: I don't have any spaced in those lines. Try inserting 5-6 blank lines before `aaa` in your input file.

Comment: Note that this will delete the first line even if it is not an empty line. I know the OP did not mention the possibility that the first line is not an empty line, but I thought it was worth mentioning anyway.

Comment: @anubhava: You are right it doesn't work. I didn't test it well enough.

Comment: Right @anubhava my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of deleting all blank lines at file start using pure BASH way without involving any external utility like awk/sed:

```
[[ "$(<file)" =~ ^[[:space:]]+(.*)$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
aaa
bbb

cc
dd
```

Comment: Better write `[[:space:]]*` just in case there are no leading blank lines. Otherwise cool method, but not really adapted to large files. `:)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I intentionally kept it as `[[:space:]]+` to avoid this operation If there are no leading blank lines and there is nothing to be removed.

Comment: Your approach breaks when there are no leading whitespace in the file, and it strips whitespace from the start of the first non-empty line.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n "H;$ {x;s/^\n*//p;}"
```

delete all first \n ant take into account that 1st line is maybe not empty (`1,/^$/` does not work in this case)